# ExposedDropdownMenuBox keeps recomposing when scrolling vertically within column

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

When scrolling up and down in the Column the ExposedDropdownMenuBox() and the attached TextFeild() recompose when .menuAnchor() is added as the user scrolls up and down the page. I have duplicated a very basic ExposedDropdownMenu to enable scrolling, but this occurs in my original project as well.

```
Column(
    modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .verticalScroll(
            rememberScrollState(),
            flingBehavior = null
        )

) {
    val options by remember {
        mutableStateOf( listOf("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3", "Option 4", "Option 5") )
    }
    var expanded by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    var name by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

    Row() {
        ExposedDropdownMenuBox(
            modifier = modifier,
            expanded = expanded,
            onExpandedChange = {
                expanded = !expanded
            }
        ) {
            TextField(
                modifier = modifier.menuAnchor(),
                value = "name",
                onValueChange = {  },
            )
        }
    }
    Row() {...}
    Row() {...}
    Row() {...}
    //ect..
}
```

I have attempted to make separate composables for each row, moving the variables into different classes, and attempted to change the variable types. I also removed the remainder of the initialization for the ExposedDropdownMenuBox() to rule out an other parts causing recomposition.